# iOS | How to use self-sizing cell for one section and fixed sizing for another section in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How to use self-sizing cell for one section and fixed-sizing cell for another section in UICollectionView?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet var collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    collectionViewLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
 }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int { 2 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 5 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // for simplicity I've removed the cell preparation code.
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
       // MySelfSizingCollectionViewCell is capable of determining cell's height, using autolayout. 
        return MySelfSizingCollectionViewCell()
    }
    else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
 }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    }
    else {
        return .init(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    }
 }
}
```

**Issue:** Above code is freezing the UI when the view controller appears. CPU usage goes to 100%. Nothing is shown.

**Requirement:** For the first section of the collection view I want to use self-sizing cells. and for rest of the section I want fixed sized which I'll return from `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`.

If I remove the `sizeForItemAt` method of flow layout delegate, then UI does not freeze, self-sizing cells displayed correctly but fixed-size cell's size get distorted.

I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: @matt, the compositional layout is available only on iOS 13 or above. For me minimum target is 11

Comment: Trouble is, in my experience there is no such thing as a self sizing cell in a flow layout.

Comment: something is there. that's why if I remove the sizeForItemAt method cell displayed at the correct size.

Comment: I followed this tutorial to achieve self sizing cell: https://www.vadimbulavin.com/collection-view-cells-self-sizing/

Comment: Have you tried adding a height constraint to the UICellectionViewCell, with the height you would return from `szieForItemAt`?